# Need to figure out how to create a hot/cold part to guessing game in python

Tags: python

I am taking my very first programming class, and asking my first question on StackOverFlow.  I am currently attempting to write a guessing game program where I have to alert the user if their guess is within 10 high or low of the user’s guess.    I am currently in chapter 5 of the *Starting out with Python* book.

Here is what the professor writes:
If the player’s guess is lower than the number generated then display the message “Too Low!” If the player’s guess is within a 10-point difference of the number generated but lower than the number generated, then give the message “Getting warm but still Low!”

I am confident that I have figured everything else out in the problem, but cannot figure out how to do the “hot/cold” option.    I have placed as comments my attempts at writing the code.

Thank you!

```
import random

def main ():
    guess_game ()
    try_again()

def guess_game():
    number = random.randint (1, 1000)
    guess_taken = 0
    while guess_taken < 100000000:
        print ('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 1000.')
        guess = float (input('Please enter a guess: '))
        guess_taken = guess_taken + 1
        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')
        #elif (number - guess) > (number - 10):
           #print ('Guess Is Hot')
        #elif (number - guess) < (number + 10):
           #print ('Guess is cold')
        else:
            guess == number
            print('Good job! You guessed my number in', guess_taken,' guesses!')
            try_again ()
            print ()

#think about doing a range somewhere

def try_again():
    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        again = input ('Would you like to play again?')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            guess_game()
        else:
            exit ()
```

Comment: The absolute value built-in function `abs()` might help you.  Try `abs(number-guess)`

Comment: Rather then going for a 4-branch if/elif, you could look at a nested if statement - e.g. something like `if guess < number: if guess < (number - 10): print "too low" else: print "warmer but too low"`

Comment: You shouldn't have a while loop in your `guess_game` function. Your code tells me you are on the right track, but that you have little to no understanding of *scope*. I recommend you learn about [scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) and then try to rewrite your solution.

Comment: @gragas that's pretty unhelpful - what's wrong with the while loop and what's that got to do with [variable] scoping?

Comment: @TomDalton Every single time you call `guess_game()`, an entirely new stack frame is acquired --- meaning the variables within the function are independent of any other call to that function. Your original function calls never terminate until the very end of your program.

Comment: @TomDalton It's very hard to explain in a 500-character comment. Try to find some videos explaining stack frames and scope. I'll try to write up a gist of a properly structured program and send it to you.

Comment: @TomDalton Actually, I retract my comment. I misread your program. One thing to note is that you can just use `while True:` and then `break`, rather than capping users at a fixed (albeit high) number of guesses.

Comment: TomDalton and gragas - I really appreciate the feedback, and as soon as I get home from the job that currently pays the bills - I am going to look into all of y'alls advice.  I am painfully new to programming, and it is probably awkward to work with such a novice.  Thank you again.  Your feedback is helpful to me and I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works. I don't have the debugger/console now.

```
import random

def main():
    while True:
        guess_game()
        schoice = try_again()
        if schoice == False:
            exit()


def guess_game():
    number = random.randint (1, 1000)
    guess_taken = 0
    while True:
        print ('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 1000.')
        while True:
            try:
                guess = float (input('Please enter a guess: '))
                break
            except:
                continue
        guess_taken = guess_taken + 1
        if guess < number:
            if (number - guess) < 10:
                print ('Guess is hot')
            else:
                print ('Guess is cold')
            print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > number:
            if (guess - number) < 10:
                print ('Guess is hot')
            else:
                print ('Guess is cold')
            print('Your guess is too high.')
        else:
            break
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in', guess_taken,' guesses!')

def try_again():
    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        again = input ('Would you like to play again?')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            return True
        else:
            return False

main()
```

If this answers all your questions then please check the tick under the up and down arrow thingy on the left with the number in the middle. If not, please comment below this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will not work.  I tested it.  Once I made a number-guessing game with hot/cold like yours and looking back at it, you will need to change this line:

```
guess = float(input('Please enter a guess: '))
```

to:

```
guess = float(int(input('Please enter a guess: ')))
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Why do you think converting to `int` before `float` will help?

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late but this might help future people looking for this. I did some minor changes to the code and this is the result. Fully tested and functional.

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    guess_the_number()
    try_again()


def guess_the_number():
    number = (random.randint(1, 1000))
    tries = 0
    print("---------------------------------------------\nYou need to guess a number between 1 and "
          "1000\n---------------------------------------------")
    while tries < 99999999999:
        guess = float(int(input("Please enter a number: ")))
        tries = tries + 1
        if guess < number:
            if (number - guess) < 10:
                print("Guess is hot")
            else:
                print("Guess is cold")
            print("Your guess is low.")
        elif guess > number:
            if (guess - number) < 10:
                print("Guess is hot")
            else:
                print("Guess is cold")
            print("Your guess is high.")
        else:
            break
    print("-------------------------------------------\nGood job! You guessed my number in", tries,
          "tries!\n-------------------------------------------")


def try_again():
    again = "y"
    while again == "y" or again == "Y" or again == "yes" or again == "Yes":
        again = input("Would you like to play again? ")
        if again == "y" or again == "Y" or again == "yes" or again == "Yes":
            return main()
        else:
            return sys.exit(0)


main()
```